# Keybinding to insert a snippet of text.

Tags: key-bindings, org-mode

I often color in red some key-words in my latex-notes taken in Org-mode.

So I often end up using `\textcolor{pink}{Blah Blah}` all over my notes.

I would like to bind `Alt+F12` to automatically expand into this snippet
with the cursor positioned on the second pair-of braces ready for input.

How would we do this?

I am using Spacemacs wrapped around emacs-24.5

Comment: Why don't you use an abbreviation instead?

Comment: Check out https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html, as suggested above. There are also packages like yasnippets for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure it's the best way to do that, but that works:

```el
(defun my/insert-pink ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "\\textcolor{pink}{}")
  (backward-char))

(defun my/add-org-pink-binding ()
   (local-set-key (kbd "<M-f12>") #'my/insert-pink))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my/add-org-pink-binding)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun my-insert-snippet ()
  "Insert snippet and move point."
  (interactive)
  (insert "\\textcolor{pink}{Blah Blah}")
  (backward-word 2))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<f12>") 'my-insert-snippet)
```